# Find the vector equation for the line concurrent to $s$ and $r$ and parallel to the plane $\pi$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have two lines:

$$r:\\x+y+2z=2\\x=y$$
$$s:\\z=x+2\\y=0$$

And I have to find the vector equation for a line $t$ that is in the plane $\pi:x-y+z=0$ and is concurrent to $r$ and $s$.

**Here's what I tried:**

In the equation of $r$ I did $y=\lambda$, then:
$$r:\\x=\lambda\\y=\lambda\\z=1-\lambda$$
And for $s$ I did $x=\lambda_2$ to get:
$$s:\\x=\lambda_2\\y=0\\z=\lambda_2+2$$

Then, a point $A$ in the line $r$ is in the form:

$$\vec{A}=(\lambda,\lambda,1-\lambda)$$
And a point $B$ in the line $s$ is:

$$\vec{B}=(\lambda_2,0,\lambda_2+2)$$

Therefore, a vector from line $r$ to $s$, $\vec{AB}$ is:
$$\vec{AB} = (\lambda_2-\lambda,-\lambda,\lambda_2-\lambda+1)$$

I know that this vector must be orthogonal to the normal vector of the plane $\pi$, but this does noe help me solve the question. Am I doing this rigth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find the intersection of the plane $\pi:x-y +z=0$ with the lines that are given (solve the linear system), and with those two points form a vector equation for your line.